# How to share information between Spring controller methods from GET and POST requests?

Tags: java, spring, post, controller, get

I'm new to Spring and I want to:

1) when an user visits *localhost/admin/users* I want the predefined options to apply

2) On *localhost/admin/users* I have some buttons that perform a `POST` with four parameters because my boss don't want me to use get (and I think is better to use `POST`, too)

3) I have a controller method `adminUsersPost` that manages the `POST` request, and I want that method to be able to make my browser to reload using the `adminUsersGet` method, but with the information sent in the `POST` request.

What I'm getting now in my browser is an alert with a webpage content in some weird encoding, I hope it is correct but I don't know.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView adminUsersGet(
    Integer page,
    Integer items,
    String sorting,
    String sortingDirection)
{
  // predefined options
  Integer pagina = 1;
  Integer itemsPorPagina = 10;
  String ordenacion = "idUsuario";
  String dirOrdenacion = "asc";
  // end of predefined options

  // Code that I want for it to use POST params from the other method


  ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("adminUsers");
  return mv;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/users", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView adminUsersPost(
    @RequestParam(value = "pagina") Integer pagina,
    @RequestParam(value = "itemsPorPagina") Integer itemsPorPagina,
    @RequestParam(value = "ordenacion") String ordenacion,
    @RequestParam(value = "dirOrdenacion") String dirOrdenacion)
{
  // Here I try to pass the POST parameters to the GET method for reloading
  // the webpage with the new content
  return adminUsersGet(pagina, itemsPorPagina, ordenacion, dirOrdenacion);
}
```

Comment: To redirect, you would use what the documentation says about redirects: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-redirecting. But what's the point of the POST method. Why use a POST if all it does is to redirect to a GET? And why use POST for what appears to be a search, which doesn't create any resource? That's what GET is for.

Comment: @JBNizet I'm very new to Spring and I only want the webpage to reload with the new options but without query string, just sharing information between Spring controller methods or redirecting from the POST manager method itself. It does not matter too much how to achieve this, but I want a URL without query string.

Comment: Then use a POST, not a GET. But it violates all web standards. What's the problem with query strings? Google uses a query string for their search, and that doesn't prevent them to be successful (on the contrary). The web has been designed by smart people. Why go against its design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern POST params-->GET same parameters is a common one. What you need is RedirectAttributes which will store your parameters into the session and redirect to your GET method. Once the GET is hit spring will automatically remove all attributes from the session, thus none of the POST parameters will be displayed in the browser url in the GET method. Have a look [here](http://www.concretepage.com/spring/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-redirectview-example-add-fetch-flash-attributes-redirectattributes-model-requestcontextutils) for a complete example and adjust it for your needs.

Comment: thanks, now I have the POST parameters on my GET manager method, but I'm getting the javascript alert instead of a page reloading. Updated code on   http://pastebin.com/8gSC4e6G